# Passar essa função Numérica de Virgula para Ponto

Tags: lua

Eu tenho uma função que retorna o numero em casa de milhar, exemplo:

```
function getMilharNumber(n) -- critico
   return tostring(math.floor(n)):reverse():gsub("(%d%d%d)","%1,"):gsub(",(%-?)$","%1"):reverse()
end

print(getMilharNumber(1000000)) -- retorna 1,000,000
```

Mas  retorna *1,000,000* com virgulas, eu quero saber como retornar com pontos assim: *1.000.000*.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode mudar o *separador decimal* na primeira chamada da função `gsub`:

```
gsub("(%d%d%d)","%1,")
--                 ↑
```

O teu código fica assim:

```
function getMilharNumber(n) -- critico
   return tostring(math.floor(n)):reverse():gsub("(%d%d%d)","%1."):gsub(",(%-?)$","%1"):reverse()
end

print(getMilharNumber(1000000)) -- retorna 1.000.000
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/FBj8WO)

Comment: deu certo obg cara! vc é fera